# how to fix invalid file name in android

Tags: android

```
This is my class file :


public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FragmentOne f = new FragmentOne();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        return root;
    }

}
```

this is my Layout name fragment_one.xml when i try to call fragment_one in class then it should Error in console This error is coming :

[2013-08-27 10:33:52 - FragmentPart] res\layout\ fragmentone.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
how to fix this Error please help me

here is the code  of frgmentone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="one" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you have already changed the name according to that, then try to do a project->clean

Comment: there seems to be a naming convention problem in your fragmentthree.xml file...plz post its code...also try renaming the file

Comment: Is this code where you added fragment_one.xml file ?

Comment: just clean build your project from project option

Comment: yes i have tried to clean many time but not fixing

Comment: Looks like you have a "space" character in the beginning of your xml file fragmentthree.xml. Try renaming the file and make sure there are no spaces in the beginning of filename.

Comment: you are adding fragment_one to the inflator while your logcat showing error for fragmentthree. please verify both the names of xml. Moreover there is a space in your name of fragmentthree.xml. Rename the file by refatoring it and clean the project.

Comment: yes i have verfiedcstill  ERROR is there

Comment: I am trying to Implement this http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/ Example

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable Error also coming

Comment: It is because of error in XML only that r is not resolved. If your xml problem is resolved then kindly clean the project.

Comment: Still Error i don't know why its coming i will delete The Project again i ll create

Comment: The necessary details to answer your question is missing, please include full source code and also full error logs.